# Using logical OR to combine inequalities.

Tags: logic, inequality

I have a physical system that must satisfy one of two inequalities:

$x\leq y$ OR $p\leq q$

But not necessarily both simultaneously.

Is there a way to combine this into a single inequality?

Obviously just adding them won't work as that would require both to be true.

Thanks for any help. All the best!

Edit: The bounds are −1≤x≤1, −1≤p≤1, 0≤y≤2, and 0≤q≤2. There are additional constraints but they are a godawful mess so I'm trying to avoid them.

Comment: I do not think there is much you can do as long as you cannot provide bounds or other restrictions for those values. If you do please tell us.

Comment: Try $(x-y)(p-q) \leq 0$

Comment: @Vikram It may not work if “OR” is “non-exclusive OR.” That is, if $x\leq y$ and $p\leq q$ both hold, then $(x-y)(p-q)\geq0$.

Comment: How about substituting $p=mx$ and $q=ny$

Comment: It obviously can, Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ otherwise. Then $f(y-x) + f(q -p) > 0$. For example, $f = signum + 1$. But I assume you have a set of functions you want to use, and $signum$ is not in it. You should include that in your question.

Comment: Hi All, the bounds are $-1\leq x \leq 1$, $-1\leq p \leq 1$, $0\leq y \leq 2$, and $0 \leq q \leq 2$. There are additional constraints but they are a godawful mess so I'm trying to avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=y-x$ and $b=q-p$.  We want $a\ge 0$ OR $b\ge 0$.  Equivalently, we want $\max\{a,b\}\ge 0$.

We have $\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|a-b|}{2}$. (This is a standard expression for the max of two numbers--geometrically the midpoint of the two numbers, plus half the distance between them.)

So for the inequality to hold, we want $\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{\mid a-b\mid}{2}\ge 0. $

We can now put this in terms of the original variables:

$x\le y$ OR $p\le q$ is equivalent to $\frac{(y-x+q-p)+\mid y-x-q+p \mid}{2} \ge 0 $

Comment: Very elegant solution! I did not believe this was possible!

Comment: @flawr: Thanks!

Comment: How clever! This is a real help, thank you :-)